# How to calculate difference in case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have something like this

```
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit END AS 'debit',
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit END AS 'credit',
```

I want to calculate difference between debit and credit

If i am using

```
Bal=CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit END  - CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit END,
```

It is giving me null value, what is wrong in this statement can anyone advice what to do here.

Comment: Use double quotes for column aliases, e.g. `"debit"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing any arithmetic on a NULL returns NULL. Make each case return 0 rather than NULL when not a condition match:

```
Bal=CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit ELSE 0 END  - 
    CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit ELSE 0 END,
```

Comment: Good catch but I would have added a `COALESCE (SecDebit , 0)` as well,  to prevent any NULL at all

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one column (CreditOrDebit) to distinguish credit or debit card then there is no need to have two columns secDebit and secCredit. So I assume there is only one column secDebitorCredit. Considering this below query will give you the final difference between debit - credit.

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN secDebitorCredit END , 0)  - 
ISNULL(CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN secDebitorCredit END, 0) )AS 'Diff'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Bal=(CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit ELSE 0 END - 
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: What's wrong in my answer? Please give a reason for the downvote?